# Is there another way except ->ownerDocument->saveXML() to get node html with tags

Tags: php, domdocument

As we know, to get node html with its inner tags we have to use

```
$node->ownerDocument->saveXML($node);
```

instead of

```
$node->nodeValue;
```

because the last method strips all the inner tags

But what if I get a node like

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('tr')[2]->getElementsByTagName('td')[5]
```

How can I get its html with its inner tags without writing lines like

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('tr')[2]->getElementsByTagName('td')[5]->ownerDocument->saveXML($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr')[2]->getElementsByTagName('td')[5])
```

Is there another shorter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't well understand what `DOMNode::ownerDocument` is. This property returns nothing more than the `DOMDocument` instance to which the `DOMNode` instance belongs (`$dom` in your code).

So you can replace your long line with:

```
$cell = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr')[2]->getElementsByTagName('td')[5];
echo $dom->saveXML($cell);
```

Note that you can also shorten your code using DOMXPath.

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $dom->saveXML($xp->query('//tr[3]/td[6]')->item(0));
```